# Pyspark explode function not working as expected

Tags: hive, apache-spark-sql

I am reading a hive table into a Pyspark dataframe. The hive table has a payload defined as string. Sample record like,

```
{
  "journal": {
    "batchName": "Test",
    "lines": [
      {
        "lineNumber": 1,
        "lineDescription": "Something",
        "companyCode": "100",
        "debit": 0,
        "credit": 27,
        "accountedDebit": 0,
        "accountedCredit": 27
      },
      {
        "lineNumber": 2,
        "lineDescription": "Somethingg",
        "companyCode": "100",
        "debit": 27,
        "credit": 0,
        "accountedDebit": 27,
        "accountedCredit": 0
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This is stored as string. I am able to extract the batchName using get_json_object() but not able to expand the lines into 2 rows. I tried to convert the lines into array and then use explode, but still it does not work. Example code follows.

```
main_data3 = main_data2.withColumn("lines_line_number2", F.regexp_replace(F.regexp_replace(F.col("lines_line_number"), '\[', ''),'\]',''))
main_data4 = main_data3.withColumn("lines_line_number3", F.array("lines_line_number2"))
main_data5 = main_data4.withColumn("lines_line_number4", F.explode("lines_line_number3")
... )
```

I want to expand and extract all the columns as is from this dataset using spark sql. I dont have the possibility to define a custom schema.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `outer_explode` and then after, a simple '*' would get all the fields in the struct as separate columns.

I created a dataframe, `df` from the string you provided.
[image]

```py
    from pyspark.sql.functions import explode_outer

    df_json = spark.read.json(df.rdd.map(lambda r: r.json))
    # Explode the lines array, which will result in struct.
    exploded_df =df_json.select(df_json.journal.batchName.alias('batchname'),explode_outer(df_json.journal.lines).alias('exploded_lines'))
    
    # Select all fields from the exploded struct.
    display(new_df_2.select('batchname', 'exploded_lines.*'))
```

[image]

Comment: This is not a Json file. It's a string field in a hive table.

Comment: @anidev711 yes, if you see the initial dataframe (df) in the screenshot, it says 'string' datatype. After loading it as string, I am converting to json format. Check it.

Comment: Understood but as I have mentioned, its a hive table, so can't read it as a JSON.

Comment: @anidev711 If you have configured your hive metastore already in spark, you can read the Hive column as a dataframe directly. `df = spark.sql('select col from table')` After this, you can continue with the code above. Try it!

Comment: please share a spark sql equivalent code for the same. I can not use a dataframe here. I have converted the string to proper type after some cleaning and then used the explode function to achieve this. I am not sure how to use the rdd.map part in a sql. Let me know if it is possible.